# how to add top features to google play app description

Tags: android, google-play

How to add this to Google play store listing ? Top Features: camera, selfies...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe these are auto-generated by Google Play based on what users say about your product in reviews in the Play store and also from answering questions. Make a great product, and users will write good reviews and get questions, and they will start appearing.

Comment: thanks. i found some information about this feature. Seems like this feature is working only on applications separately reviewed by google team